Why does Linux not cycle through available WLAN access points on single AP authentication denied?
When I am in the first floor, there are places where I have a stronger signal from the router [1] than the Fritz 1750E repeater, but the connection with the router fails again and again [2]. So I have to set the BSSID (Basic Service Set Identifier) explicitly to connect with the repeater. Why is Linux not trying other access points when it notices that the connection to one of them fails multiple times?
[1] checked by using sudo iwlist $NETWORK_INTERFACE_NAME scan | grep -B 5 -i $SSID
[2]
[12697.556999] wlp0s20f3: authenticate with ROUTER_ADDRESS (local address=LOCAL_ADDRESS)
[12697.557972] wlp0s20f3: send auth to ROUTER_ADDRESS (try 1/3)
[12697.597683] wlp0s20f3: ROUTER_ADDRESS denied authentication (status 34)

My Thoughts
The only explanation that comes to my mind is that switching the AP should usually not fix this issue and therefore there is no implementation to solve this error that way.
AP Placement
My parents live in a four-storey house have one router (FRITZ!Box 7590; second floor) and two repeaters (Fritz!Repeater 1750E; second floor and FRITZ!Repeater 2400; fourth floor) that are in a Mesh configuration - not all apartments are rented by my parents. The house is quite old which leads to weak signal through ceilings and walls.
Relevant Information From Questions
Guest-WLAN Works!
I was able to create a guest WLAN and I can connect to that WLAN without issues. I also made sure that my device is not blacklisted for whatever reason in the regular WLAN.
Are you using iwd or wpa_supplicant as the software handling roaming & authentication?
xaver@xaver-latitude-3400:~$ systemctl list-units --type=service | grep -E 'iwd|wpa'
  wpa_supplicant.service                                loaded active running WPA supplicant
xaver@xaver-latitude-3400:~$ ps aux | grep -E 'iwd|wpa_supplicant'
root        1035  0.0  0.1  18392 11136 ?        Ss   09:13   0:07 /usr/sbin/wpa_supplicant -u -s -O DIR=/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
xaver      20659  0.0  0.0   9276  2176 pts/1    S+   14:30   0:00 grep --color=auto -E iwd|wpa_supplicant

More Debug By Using journalctl
First increased debug leven: busctl set-property fi.w1.wpa_supplicant1 /fi/w1/wpa_supplicant1 fi.w1.wpa_supplicant1 DebugLevel s debug for wpa_supplicant and nmcli gen log level debug for network manager. Then checking journalctl -b -u wpa_supplicant -u NetworkManager -f for any messages immediately after authentication fails.
[...]
Nov 26 14:07:56 user-latitude-3400 NetworkManager[1031]: <info>  [1732626476.7391] device (wlp0s20f3): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> authenticating
Nov 26 14:07:56 user-latitude-3400 NetworkManager[1031]: <info>  [1732626476.7391] device (p2p-dev-wlp0s20f3): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> authenticating
Nov 26 14:07:56 user-latitude-3400 wpa_supplicant[1036]: nl80211: Ignored event 37 (NL80211_CMD_AUTHENTICATE) for foreign interface (ifindex 3 wdev 0x0)
Nov 26 14:07:56 user-latitude-3400 wpa_supplicant[1036]: nl80211: Drv Event 37 (NL80211_CMD_AUTHENTICATE) received for wlp0s20f3
Nov 26 14:07:56 user-latitude-3400 wpa_supplicant[1036]: nl80211: Authenticate event
Nov 26 14:07:56 user-latitude-3400 wpa_supplicant[1036]: wlp0s20f3: Event AUTH (10) received
Nov 26 14:07:56 user-latitude-3400 wpa_supplicant[1036]: wlp0s20f3: SME: Authentication response: peer=ROUTER_MAC auth_type=0 auth_transaction=2 status_code=34
Nov 26 14:07:56 user-latitude-3400 wpa_supplicant[1036]: wlp0s20f3: CTRL-EVENT-AUTH-REJECT ROUTER_MAC auth_type=0 auth_transaction=2 status_code=34
Nov 26 14:07:56 user-latitude-3400 wpa_supplicant[1036]: wlp0s20f3: Radio work 'sme-connect'@0x5696ace65f80 done in 0.043433 seconds
Nov 26 14:07:56 user-latitude-3400 wpa_supplicant[1036]: wlp0s20f3: radio_work_free('sme-connect'@0x5696ace65f80): num_active_works --> 0
Nov 26 14:07:56 user-latitude-3400 wpa_supplicant[1036]: Added BSSID ROUTER_MAC into ignore list, ignoring for 10 seconds
ov 26 14:07:56 user-latitude-3400 wpa_supplicant[1036]: wlp0s20f3: Another BSS in this ESS has been seen; try it next
Nov 26 14:07:56 user-latitude-3400 wpa_supplicant[1036]: BSSID ROUTER_MAC ignore list count incremented to 2, ignoring for 10 seconds
Nov 26 14:07:56 user-latitude-3400 wpa_supplicant[1036]: Continuous association failures - consider temporary network disabling
Nov 26 14:07:56 user-latitude-3400 wpa_supplicant[1036]: wlp0s20f3: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-TEMP-DISABLED id=0 ssid="WLAN_SSID" auth_failures=1 duration=10 reason=CONN_FAILED
Nov 26 14:07:56 user-latitude-3400 wpa_supplicant[1036]: wlp0s20f3: Consecutive connection failures: 7 --> request scan in 10000 ms
Nov 26 14:07:56 user-latitude-3400 wpa_supplicant[1036]: wlp0s20f3: Setting scan request: 10.000000 sec
Nov 26 14:07:56 user-latitude-3400 NetworkManager[1031]: <info>  [1732626476.7776] device (wlp0s20f3): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> disconnected
Nov 26 14:07:56 user-latitude-3400 wpa_supplicant[1036]: wlp0s20f3: State: AUTHENTICATING -> DISCONNECTED
Nov 26 14:07:56 user-latitude-3400 NetworkManager[1031]: <info>  [1732626476.7776] device (p2p-dev-wlp0s20f3): supplicant management interface state: authenticating -> disconnected
[...]


Are you using iwd or wpa_supplicant as the software handling roaming & authentication? (The kernel on its own does not do that.) And of course, why do you have an ESSID with mismatching authentication in the first place?

I don't know how to answer your questions. Can you tell me how I can find out whether I am using iwd or wpa_supplicant as the software handling roaming & authentication? I will add to the question what I found via google. I don't know why the mismatch happens.

You have wpa_supplicant in the process list, and -u likely means it's controlled by NetworkManager, so I'd suggest running busctl set-property fi.w1.wpa_supplicant1 /fi/w1/wpa_supplicant1 fi.w1.wpa_supplicant1 DebugLevel s debug for the former and nmcli gen log level debug for the latter – to make them generate more detailed log messages – and then checking journalctl -b -u wpa_supplicant -u NetworkManager (maybe with -n 100 for less output or -f to follow live) for any messages immediately after authentication fails.

I have gathered the log information, but I have a hard time identifying what the relevant part in the log is which makes it unfit to add it to the question. These are the logs that occurred while trying to access the WLAN without specifying the AP which failed: https://pastebin.com/AUdLPSeR
I have regex replaced some MACs: the AP's with ACCESS_POINT_MAC, the router's with ROUTER_MAC and the rest with OTHER_MAC.

I've added a part that I think might be relevant, but I don't see an explanation on what kind of error actually occurs.

From the logs – Another BSS in this ESS has been seen; try it next followed by Continuous association failures - consider temporary network disabling – it seems that wpa_supplicant does cycle through available APs, but it also has a hard-coded limit of 3 (4?) auth rejections for the ESS as a whole.
It seems that error code 34 is WLAN_STATUS_DENIED_POOR_CHANNEL_CONDITIONS, i.e. the router is rejecting the client due to weak signal (although the log doesn't have the "OCE: RSSI-based association rejection" message that should accompany it). Unfortunately, wpa_supplicant has no other special treatment for this error code, i.e. it still counts as a reject like any other.
So it might be that the router has been configured with an excessively strict signal strength limit (or some other reason?) and enough failures have accumulated while the router was the only BSS in range, and by the time your repeater finally showed up in scan results, wpa_supplicant had just given up on the ESSID in general. My first suggestion is to look through your router's Wi-Fi settings for such a limit.
If your Linux distribution has a package for the iwd wireless daemon, that might handle such situations better (as it is more modern in general, and seems to have a special case for such "temporary" rejects specifically) – NetworkManager has experimental support for iwd through the wifi.backend option, although iwd is somewhat resistant to being integrated.

Given that I can connect to the same router's guest network (my latest update; hadn't tried that before), that would mean there would be two settings for signal strength limit - but I can't find one. That doesn't have to mean it's not the case though.
